# How can I use ExchangeService to access a shared mailbox (Outlook 2013)

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to access a second mailbox in outlook using an ExchangeService. but when I run the application it grabs my main email. Its worth noting that I use windows authentication here, and that I need to for this to work.

```
var useExchangeServer = new UseExchangeServer("SECONDEMAIL@mycompany.com");
var messages = useExchangeServer.LoadMessages(1);

foreach (var message in messages){ //At this point message has the wrong email...
...
}
```

here is my "UseExchangeServer" class

```
public UseExchangeServer(string mailBox)
    {
        _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        _service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        _service.AutodiscoverUrl(mailBox);
    }

public FindItemsResults<Item> GetLastItems(int numberOfItems)
    {
        return _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(numberOfItems));
    }

public IEnumerable<EmailMessage> LoadMessages(int numberOfMessages)
    {
        var findResults = GetLastItems(numberOfMessages);

        foreach (var item in findResults.Items)
        {
            var message = EmailMessage.Bind(_service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));
            message.Load();
            yield return message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the FolderId overload to specify the Mailbox you want to access otherwise the Mailbox that belongs to the credentials you are using will be used so you will need to do something like the following with your code

```
public UseExchangeServer(string mailBox)
{
    _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    _service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    _service.AutodiscoverUrl(mailBox);
}

 public FindItemsResults<Item> GetLastItems(int numberOfItems,string mailBox)
{
    FolderId FolderToAccess = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,mailBox);
    return _service.FindItems(FolderToAccess, new ItemView(numberOfItems));
}

public IEnumerable<EmailMessage> LoadMessages(int numberOfMessages)
{
    var findResults = GetLastItems(numberOfMessages);

    foreach (var item in findResults.Items)
    {
        var message = EmailMessage.Bind(_service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));
        message.Load();
        yield return message;
    }
}
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: It wont let me up vote because im still a newbie but this was the answer thanks a bunch!!!!

Comment: @glen-scales Messages and appointments are read ok, but it can't read contacts using `new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts,mailBox);`  (in outlook contacts are shown as `\\SECONDEMAIL` instead of `SECONDEMAIL@mycompany.com"`

Comment: by the way it's a shared mailbox I'm trying to read contacts from

Comment: This will only work if contacts folder in the Target Mailbox is the default contacts folder (eg if its just a user created contacts folder that has been shared it won't work). Else you would need to know the Id of the folder your trying to bind to.